# antlr4 for python target error: NameError: global name 'XX' is not defined

Tags: python, compiler-construction, antlr4

I am using Antlr4 for Python target code. In the grammar file, I have a rule that needs to get text of a token. But I get error for that.

The code looks like this

```
//parser
variables : VARS COLON (ID {declare_variable(ID.text)})+;
...
//lexer
VARS : 'variables';
COLON: ':';
ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')* ;
...
```

I compile the parser/lexer using

```
java -Xmx500M -cp /usr/local/lib/antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.Tool -Dlanguage=Python2 Grammar.g4
```

Then I run

```
python main.py test.txt
```

Which is when I get the following error :

```
NameError: global name 'ID' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without seeing the whole grammar (being Python, I understand it's large), but I suspect the `ID.text` thing is causing the error.  Where exactly does the error occur?

Comment: @TomServo yes that is true. But I don't see how I am supposed to get the text of ID then. I have updated the question with compile command. Is it what you asked for?

Comment: You get the value in your listener or visitor.  At runtime, not compile time.

Comment: @TomServo Can't I get it like above, in the action of a rule, at run time?

Comment: In your grammar, instead of "ID", use "$ID". See https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/actions.md. You can use Antlr actions if actions need to influence the parse, but generally you work with Visitors and Listeners after parsing because Antlr actions are written in a specific target language, which then makes your grammar only work for that target. I see a lot of grammars that have Java embedded in actions or members and then have to rip out that code.

Comment: @kaby76 I had already tried $ID . That leads to another error (although it works for cpp). I have started to implement Visitors. Thanks for the help.